# Phoenix update Statement with java

Tags: java, hbase, phoenix-framework

I used the below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-alpha-HBase-2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-queryserver-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0-HBase-1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to update a field in hbase from jdbc (Phoenix).

```
System.out.println("Phoenix connected");
st = conn.createStatement();
int rst = 0;
st.executeUpdate(updatequery);
//conn.commit();
st.close();
conn.close();
```

But I'm getting an error.

I used thick connection . Can you help me this error . You meet this error before ?

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValueUtil.length(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell)'    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixKeyValueUtil.calculateMutationDiskSize(PhoenixKeyValueUtil.java:180)
```

updatedquery = "UPSERT INTO "ui_dataset_hbase"("+ ""cf1"."b",ROWKEY)"+" "+"VALUES("+"'"+a+"',"+id+")" );

conn.commit give error . I used executeUpdate but if my code is run , a is not updated

I Changed my code below . but do not update field in phoenix .My code works without failed. Bu not update a field  .Please help me this topic??

System.out.println("Phoenix connected");
st = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "UPSERT INTO "ui_dataset_hbase" (ROWKEY, "cf1"."a") VALUES (107, '5')";

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //ps.setInt(1, 107);
    //ps.setString(2, "123123");
    try {
        ps.execute(sql);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //boolean rst = true;
    //rst = st.execute(updatequery);
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    //conn.commit();
    st.close();
    conn.close();
    return true;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace. Also, what is `updatequery`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I share my update query